# Why ui-grid.woff changes to and HTML like file when I use ui-grid.css from local host?

Tags: css, angular-ui-grid, woff

This is a strange thing I have noticed.
I am using angular ui-grid 4.11.1.

Everything works fine except ui-grid.woff loading part.

If I use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.11.1/ui-grid.min.css"/>
```

the woff file gets downloaded from a remote location.

If I use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui-grid/4-11-1/ui-grid.css" />
```

woff file gets downloaded from the local matching.

I see from the browser debug window that in the latter case, the downloaded woff file turns into a kind of HTML file. So the ui-grid can't parse it.

I am not able to figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the directory name from **4.11.1** from **4-11-1** has resolved this issue. Still don't know why it was happening when a directory name has a hyphen (-) in it.

From

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui-grid/4-11-1/ui-grid.css" />
```

changed to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui-grid/4.11.1/ui-grid.css" />
```